# Vim - error messages timeout

Tags: vim

I want Vim to timeout error messages in the command line after 5 seconds or so. What's the way to do it?

Currently an error message (e.g. `E486: Pattern not found...`) hangs there until it's cleared by some other action.

Answer (score 3):

You can clear the message in the command-line via `:echo`. The [`CursorHold`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#CursorHold) event can be used for triggering when you're idle for some time (default 4 seconds). You can also add more events (e.g. `CursorMoved`, `FocusLost`, etc.) according to your preferences. (But having an exact timeout N seconds after an error occurs would be very hard to implement, as there's no hook for that.) Taken together, you can define the following (e.g. in your `~/.vimrc`):

```
:autocmd CursorHold * echo
```